# What are the best suitable type of image moments (Hu, Zernike etc.) that can be applied on an Image after DCT/DWT?

Tags: dwt

I want to perform a block by block comparison by using overlapping blocks and their respective image moments.
Can anybody suggest for type of image moment suited for blocks of DCT/DWT of that image. Hu moments are working fine for uint8 image but do not perform for DCT/DWT of same image.in DWT i wish to work on LL band.